# Enable users to read only specific issues

Tags: youtrack

I need to grant access to a user (or group) from an external organization to our YouTrack system, allowing them to view and track progress on specific issues. However, I want to restrict their access so they can only see certain issues, designated with the tag 'visible to externals.' I do not want the external user to have access to the entire project or all its issues, only those specifically marked.
Youtrack Server Build 2023.2.21228

I tried to set up roles and permissions for groups and projects, but I couldn't achieve the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to allow these user/groups access to the entire project, but prior to that explicitly limit the visibility of existing issues to, say, a project team.

You'll also need to make sure the Default visibility setting in your project is also set to this group(s) of internal users (e.g. the project team). This is needed for all newly created issues to be invisible to the external users.

Lastly, you'll need a workflow rule that will react to issues getting tagged by the 'visible to externals' tag. This rule would then clear the permittedGroups property of the issue.